# Microsoft Academic Graph Search - retrieving all papers from a journal within a time-frame?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm currently trying to learn how to use Microsoft Knowledge API, specifically the Graph Search method. *I want to try and retrieve all the publications made by a specified journal* initially, and then try and provide a time-frame for results returned.

Current request:

```
{
  "path": "/author/PaperIDs/paper/JournalID/journal",
  "author": {
    "type": "Author",
    "select": [ "DisplayAuthorName" ],
    "match": { "Name": "jim miles" }
  },
  "paper": {
    "type": "Paper",
    "select": [ "OriginalTitle", "CitationCount", "PublishYear", "DOI", "OriginalVenue" , "JournalID"],
    "return": { "PublishYear": { "gt": 2013, "lt": 2015 } }
  },
    "journal": {
    "type": "Journal",
    "select": [ "Name", "NormalizedName", "NormalizedShortName"]
  }
}
```

Documents used to get this far:
[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThIiu.png)
[API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/graphsearchmethod)

What is missing from my understanding to create this request? Is there another set of documentation available, as the Microsoft references lack basic information such as lists of attributes available for a given context (i.e. journal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your task is to get all publications from a specific journal in a specific time frame, the [Evaluate API](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/565d753be597ed16ac3ffc03/console) should meet your needs and has a [well-documented schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/paperentityattributes).

For example, the following expression would get you papers in the journal "Educational Technology Research and Development" between the year 2013 and 2015:
And(Composite(J.JId=114840262),Y=[2013,2015])

Sample URL:
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=And(Composite(J.JId=114840262),Y=[2013,2015])&model=latest&count=10&offset=0&attributes=Id,Ti,J.JN,J.JId,Y&subscription-key=your_subscription_key

Comment: EDIT: Found my key.

Is there a way to get a list of attributes available for the parts of the Composite parameters? Such as to search by Journal Name?

Comment: To see the attributes that are available when querying for papers, see [Paper Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/paperentityattributes) documentation. The "composite" expression syntax needs to be used whenever you leverage an entity attribute that has a "." in the name, i.e. "J.JN" (journal name).