# Get Information from Microsoft Academic Graph API

Tags: python, academic-graph

I am trying to use the Microsoft Academic Graph API with Python, to get information about the Author's Affiliations. However, the information provided in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/graphsearchmethod

is not clear to me.

I have also read [Microsoft Academic Graph Search - retrieving all papers from a journal within a time-frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100350/microsoft-academic-graph-search-retrieving-all-papers-from-a-journal-within-a?rq=1)

I am trying with something like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/graph/search"

querystring = {"mode":"json%0A"}

payload = "{}"

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

What should I put in "payload" to retrieve the affiliation of, for example, the Author "John Doe" ?

Comment: Your first link, to the Microsoft docs page, includes a full example of what a query payload might look like 0 just underneath the text `For the json search, if we want to get the papers whose titles contain "graph engine" and written by "bin shao", we can specify the query as follows.`

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but i dont get any results. Also i dont know how to get the affiliation of one particular author

Comment: @DanielleM., when I try the particular example you tell me I  get: {
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Resource not found"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using the wrong endpoint.
As for anything experimental the documentation seems out of date.
I have had success calling `https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate`
These endpoints can be seen in the [cognitive labs documentation](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/565d9001ca73072048922d97).

I am yet to figure out how to retrieve academic profiles, as the query below yields no results, whereas academic.microsoft.com has loads.

`https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(AA.AuN='Harry L. Anderson')&model=latest&count=10&attributes=Id,Ti,AA.AuN,E,AA.AuId`

Hope this may help anyone stumbling upon this.

Update :

Here is a working query for the same author :
`https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?model=latest&count=100&expr=Composite(AA.AuN=='harry l anderson')&attributes=Id,Ti,AA.AuN,E,AA.AuId`

Notice the author name has to be in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

there's a tool for migrating the MAG into an Apache Elasticsearch ;)

https://github.com/vwoloszyn/mag2elasticsearch